# javafx rectangle onmouseclick event (fxml)

Tags: javafx

I'm currently programming a game called Farkle. I want to add a OnMouseClick Event for each rectangle that represent a dice.

My problem is that the rectangle doesn't recognize the MouseEvent. I built my GUI with the Scene Builder. This is an extract of my FXML Code:

```
<Rectangle fx:id="recDice1" arcHeight="5.0" arcWidth="5.0" fill="WHITE" 
height="40.0" onMouseClicked="#recDice1_OnMouseClicked" stroke="BLACK" 
strokeType="INSIDE" width="40.0" GridPane.halignment="CENTER" 
GridPane.valignment="CENTER" />
```

The Rectangle is in a GridPane and the GridPane is ordered on the left side of a BorderPane.

And this is the extract of my Java code:

```
@FXML private Rectangle recDice1;
@FXML public void recDice1_OnMouseClicked(MouseEvent event){
    System.out.println("Funktioniert!");
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    this.primaryStage = primaryStage;
    this.primaryStage.setTitle("Farkle");

    initLayout();

}

    public void initLayout(){
    try {
        //Erstelle FXMLLoader
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("../gui/FarkleGUI.fxml"));
        loader.setController(new FarkleControl());
        rootLayout = (BorderPane) loader.load();



        //Lade Szene
        Scene scene = new Scene(rootLayout);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setResizable(false);

        //Setze Grösse der Stage (Somit entfallen Margins)
        primaryStage.sizeToScene();

        //Zeige Szene
        primaryStage.show();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
```

Imports:

```
package java2.farkle.mlz.control;

import java.io.IOException;

import javafx.application.Application;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;

import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
```

Like I said at the beginning the rectangle doesn't recognize the MouseEvent. I tried the same with a Button and it worked fine.

Comment: If you are using Scenebuilder, one can assume that you are using MVC ideas. Yet, in your code you are not. The FXML file that you altered using Scenebuilder has a controller file that you should be working with. In MVC in almost every case you should do nothing to the Main file. Your @FXML code should be in the controller that's associated with the FXML file.

Answer (score 2):

Here is something you can analyze.

> Main:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 *
 * @author blj0011
 */
public class Farkle extends Application
{

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception
    {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FXMLDocument.fxml"));

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

> FXML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.RowConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="200" prefWidth="320" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.111" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="farkle.FXMLDocumentController">
    <children>
        <Button fx:id="button" layoutX="128.0" layoutY="155.0" onAction="#handleOnButtonAction" text="Click Me!" />
      <GridPane layoutX="6.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
        <columnConstraints>
          <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
          <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
        </columnConstraints>
        <rowConstraints>
          <RowConstraints minHeight="100.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
        </rowConstraints>
         <children>
            <Rectangle fx:id="recDice1" arcHeight="5.0" arcWidth="5.0" fill="DODGERBLUE" height="100.0" onMouseClicked="#handleOnMouseClicked" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE" width="160.0" />
            <Rectangle fx:id="recDice2" arcHeight="5.0" arcWidth="5.0" fill="DODGERBLUE" height="100.0" onMouseClicked="#handleOnMouseClicked" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE" width="160.0" GridPane.columnIndex="1" />
         </children>
      </GridPane>
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

> Controller:

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;

/**
 *
 * @author blj0011
 */
public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable
{    
    @FXML
    private void handleOnButtonAction(ActionEvent event)
    {
        System.out.println("You clicked button: " + ((Button)event.getSource()).getId());
    }

    @FXML private void handleOnMouseClicked(MouseEvent event)
    {
        System.out.println("You clicked rectangle: " + ((Rectangle)event.getSource()).getId());
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb)
    {
        // TODO
    }        
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried your code but it didn't work for me. I won't use FXML it's easier for me to code the GUI.

Comment: If the answer was the solution to your problem, you should select it as the correct answer.